# Multi Nested Expand and collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a nested expandable and collapse tab.
I am able to implement the first level. i.e. If I click on key1, it will expand the list.

However, for key 5, when I click on it, both the second level and third level expand. Is there a way that when I click on key 5, only the second level will expand.

Is there any better way to create a nested expand and collapsable data?

https://jsfiddle.net/charles30hk/8ykLdnox/

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="archive_0">
  <li class="level_0">key1
    <ul class="archive_1">
      <li class="level_1">key11     value11</li>
      <li class="level_1">key12     value12</li>
    </ul></li><li class="level_0">key2     value2</li>
    <li class="level_0">key3     value3</li>
    <li class="level_0">key4     value3</li>
    <li class="level_0">key5
      <ul class="archive_1">
        <li class="level_1">key51     value11</li>
        <li class="level_1">key52     value12</li>
        <li class="level_1">key53<ul class="archive_2">
          <li class="level_2">key531     value</li>
          <li class="level_2">key52     value12</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.archive_0 ul').hide();

$('.level_0').click(function() {
    //$(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});


$('.archive_1 ul').hide();

$('.level_1').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});

$('.archive_2 ul').hide();

$('.level_2').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});

$('.archive_3 ul').hide();

$('.level_3').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually simplify your code quite a lot using a bit of css and multiple selector calls:

**CSS**

```
.archive_1, .archive_2, .archive_3 {display: none}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.level_0, .level_1, .level_2, .level_3').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

[Updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8ykLdnox/1/)

The key here, as the other answers mention is `e.stopPropogation()` - [a good read](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your level_1 function is finding all children ul and expanding them all, change your selector to get only the first level of children:

```
$('.level_0').click(function() {
    $(this).find(' > ul').slideToggle();
});
```

When you click on children elements, you will also need to stop the click event propagating to the parent too (as the child is within the parent, clicking on a child clicks the parent too). To stop the propagation do:

```
$('.level_1').click(function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.children('ul:eq(0)').toggle()` and `e.stopPropagation()`. You are hiding each ul individually, you could do only `$('.archive_0 ul').hide()`.

```
$('.archive_0 ul').hide();
$('li').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).children('ul:eq(0)').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```js
$('.archive_0 ul').hide();
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).children('ul:eq(0)').toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
#level_1,
#level_2,
#level_3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.archive_0 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.archive_1 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  list-style-type: circle;
  font-size: medium;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.archive_2 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  list-style: square url('http://www.webbossuk.com/admin/images/reply-arrow.png');
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="archive_0">
  <li class="level_0">key1
    <ul class="archive_1">
      <li class="level_1">key11 value11</li>
      <li class="level_1">key12 value12</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level_0">key2 value2</li>
  <li class="level_0">key3 value3</li>
  <li class="level_0">key4 value3</li>
  <li class="level_0">key5
    <ul class="archive_1">
      <li class="level_1">key51 value11</li>
      <li class="level_1">key52 value12</li>
      <li class="level_1">key53
        <ul class="archive_2">
          <li class="level_2">key531 value</li>
          <li class="level_2">key52 value12</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:first` selector to select first child.

Also you should use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. clicking on a child `ul` will also fire click of parent `ul`.

Following is the sample:

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/8ykLdnox/2/)

```js
$('.archive_0 ul, .archive_1 ul, .archive_2 ul .archive_2 ul').hide();

$('.level_0,.level_1,.level_2,.level_3').on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).find('ul:first').slideToggle();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
});
```

```css
#level_1,
#level_2,
#level_3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.archive_0 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.archive_1 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  list-style-type: circle;
  font-size: medium;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.archive_2 {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  list-style: square url('http://www.webbossuk.com/admin/images/reply-arrow.png');
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="archive_0">
  <li class="level_0">key1
    <ul class="archive_1">
      <li class="level_1">key11 value11</li>
      <li class="level_1">key12 value12</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level_0">key2 value2</li>
  <li class="level_0">key3 value3</li>
  <li class="level_0">key4 value3</li>
  <li class="level_0">key5
    <ul class="archive_1">
      <li class="level_1">key51 value11</li>
      <li class="level_1">key52 value12</li>
      <li class="level_1">key53
        <ul class="archive_2">
          <li class="level_2">key531 value</li>
          <li class="level_2">key52 value12</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it hides your `.archive_2` when you click on `.level_0`,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".level_0 > .archive_1").hide();
$(".level_0").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".archive_2").hide();
    $(this).find(".archive_1").slideToggle();
});
});
```